# One shot monostable multivibrator with OA, output active low

Tags: operational-amplifier, monostable, one-shot

I need to make a one-shot multivibrator with a OA, since in the main design, one OA is available form a package with 4 (single supply).

Triggering can be either POS or NEG since I can adapt the circuit before.
What I really need is OUT pulse to be active low.

What I simulated is this schematic, but the output pulse is active high.
Of course I can invert it with a transistor, but I wonder if it can be done with a single OA :)

[image]
[image]

Thanks for any ideas :)

PS. Currently I use a NAND one-shot multivibrator design that I try to replace with a OA.

Comment: I would try turning the diode around the other way and changing the triggering to positive. Try that and let us know the results.

On second thought, you might not need to turn the diode around. I'm going to have to set it up in ltspice and try it myself.

Comment: I don't have the TS27X model and I can't get this to sim with any other opamp I've tried. Did that model come with LTSpice?

Comment: Just use any OA from library that works with single supply, 15V, rail to rail

Comment: I've tried several, all I get is the original pulses inverted, no latching action.